# Date range in "if" statement

Tags: javascript, date, if-statement

I have this piece of code:

```
function auto_select_param_call_time() {
    if (today() == date("02.01.2017") || today() == date("03.01.2017")) {
        auto_click_param("call_time", "Non-working day");
    } else {
        //Do something else
    }
}
```

As you can see, it checks if it's any holidays today.
Now there are around 8 new holidays I need to add to this 'If'.
If just write them all down like "today() == date("02.01.2017")" it will turn really ugly and big really fast.

Is there any way I can write a range of dates? For example, "if it between 06.05.2017 and 9.05.2017, then...", WITHOUT using a switch?

Or any other way?

Comment: `if(today() > date("06.05.2017") || today() <   date("06.05.2017"))`, you mean like that?

Comment: @George well, that's embarrassing.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't compare javascript Date objects directly for equality. You should work with Date.getTime() which is a number you can use for equality tests. This works only when both dates have the same time of day as well (for example 00:00:00.000)

Comment: You could also check the [momentJS](http://momentjs.com/) library, as it is very powerful for handling dates. However, as @George pointed out, it may be useful if you have a great amount of date-handling code - importing the whole library just for this comparison may be overkill.

Answer (score 0):

> As you can see, it checks if it's any holidays today.

I can't see that from the code. Where I live, "02.01.2017" (2 Jan 2017) is a public holiday in lieu of 1 Jan, which is a Sunday. But "03.01.2017" (3 Jan 2017) is not a public holiday.

What you might do is write an array of dates that are public holidays and see if a date is equal to one of those, e.g.

```js
// Helper to format date as local ISO 8601 date only
if (!Date.prototype.toISODateLocal) {
  Date.prototype.toISODateLocal = function() {
    return this.getFullYear() + '-'  +
      ('0' + (this.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '-' +
      ('0' + this.getDate()).slice(-2);  
  };
}

/* Check if date is a holiday
** @param {Date} date - date to check
** @returns {Boolean} true if date is a public holiday, 
** otherwise false
*/
function isHoliday(date) {
  var dateString = date.toISODateLocal();
  var holidays = ['2017-01-02','2017-04-14','2017-04-17'];
  return holidays.indexOf(dateString) > -1;
}

[new Date(2017,0,2),
 new Date(2017,3,14),
 new Date()].forEach(function(date) {
   console.log(date.toISODateLocal() + ' is ' +
     (isHoliday(date)? '':'not ') + 'a holiday.');
});
```

You could use an object with start and end dates for contiguous holidays, but most aren't date ranges so I think simpler to just use an array of the particular days. There are only about a dozen each year so not a big issue either way.

If you want to see if a date is between two other dates, you can use the comparison `<` and `>` operators, e.g.

```js
// See if date falls on 1 Jan to 10 Jan inclusive
var rangeStart = new Date(2017,0,1);  // Start of 1 Jan
var rangeEnd = new Date(2017,0,10,23,59,59,999); // End of 10 Jan

[new Date(2017,0,5),  //  5 Jan
 new Date(2017,0,10), // 10 Jan
 new Date(2017,0,11)  // 11 Jan
].forEach(function(date) {
  console.log(date + ' in range? ' + (date >= rangeStart && date <= rangeEnd));
})
```